# HTML5 Form required field with normal button (not Submit)

Tags: javascript, html

I have some form fields and a Save button (not Submit type). I want to implement the HTML5 required validation
using

However it seems to work only with Submit button and not with normal button.

I cannot use Submit button, since I have custom code on my Save button

```
$("#saveForm").click(function(){
        saveFormData();
        showView('detailsView','editView');
        setFormFieldValues();
    })
```

How can I achieve the same with normal button ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use submit button. just add return false at the end like this :

```
$("#saveForm").click(function(){
    saveFormData();
    showView('detailsView','editView');
    setFormFieldValues();
    return false;     //stops the form being submitted
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add your custom code to the submit event of the form:

```
$("form").on("submit",function(event){

    saveFormData();
    showView('detailsView','editView');
    setFormFieldValues();




});
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
$("#saveForm").click(function(event){

    var emptyFields = $('input').filter('[required][value=""]');
    if (emptyFields.length === 0) {
       /* valid code here */
    } else {
       /* invalid code here */
       event.preventDefault(); // this stops the click event;
    }
}
```

You can loop through the empty fields using `emptyFields.each()`

Comment: Thx a lot...I like this...Only thing this is only working for the first field.....not for all the 4 fields that i have...

Answer (score 0):

You could use form submit event and prevent the default behavior (posting to server) using `e.preventDefault();`

```
$("form").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    saveFormData();
    showView('detailsView','editView');
    setFormFieldValues();
});
```